Weird NT Question Related with Primes
Find the number of pairs of natural numbers $(k, p)$ with the following properties:
1)$p$ is a prime number
2)$k \leq 2p$
3)$k^{p-1}|(p-1)^{k} +1$
4)$k \neq 1$
Now i tried random stuff like:
Case 1($p=2$): Trivially $k=2$.
Case 2($p$ is a odd prime):
So $k$ is odd. So let $k=2t-1$. Hence values of $t$ can be $2...,q$.
Note: I did some other random stuff but idk how to use it... or felt it was irrelevent.
Tried once using mod arithmethic and once using inequalities... i could not do it in a clean way dont want to stop ur thought proccess tho so ull can try those methods.
Pls help!! Thank you!!

Where does this problem come from?

my friends friend shared it to me @Aphelli

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the AoPS threads NT problem, Number theory, Find all pairs, IMO ShortList 1999, number theory problem 1, etc.

damn i never knew these kinds of softwares existed

@Aphelli FYI, the AoPS thread IMO ShortList 1999, number theory problem 1 indicates that, apart from the extra requirement that $k \neq 1$, the problem is from the $1999$ IMO ShortList.

First, consider $p = 2$. We then have $k \mid 2 \;\to\; k = 2$, so $(2, 2)$ is a solution, as you noted.
Next, with $p$ being an odd prime, then $k$ is odd, as you've already noted. Since $k \neq 1$, it has must have at least one odd prime factor. Let $q$ be the smallest prime factor of $k$. Thus, we have
$$(p - 1)^k + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{q} \;\;\to\;\; (p - 1)^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$$
Using the multiplicative order, let
$$m = \operatorname{ord}_q(p - 1) \;\to\; m \mid 2k$$
If $m$ is odd, then $m \mid k$ so $(p - 1)^k \equiv 1\pmod{q}$, contradicting $(p - 1)^2 \equiv -1\pmod{q}$. Thus, $m$ must be even. However, it can't be greater than $2$ since, as $q$ is the smallest prime factor of $k$, it would require that $m \ge 2q$ but $m \le q - 1$. Thus, $m = 2$, so using $(p - 1)^k \equiv -1\pmod{q}$, we get
$$(p - 1)^{k - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; p - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; p \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$
In other words, $q$ just be $p$. Since $k \le 2p$, this means that $k = q = p$. As such, the divisibility requirement is now
$$p^{p - 1} \mid (p - 1)^p + 1$$
Using a binomial expansion, or the Lifting-the-exponent lemma, we get
$$\nu_p((p - 1)^p + 1) = \nu_p((p - 1) + 1) + \nu_p(p) = 2$$
Thus, $p - 1\le 2 \;\to\; p \le 3$, so $(3, 3)$ is the only other solution.
In total, the only solutions are $(k, p) \in \{(2, 2), (3, 3)\}$.
